# промежуток времени между текущим кадром и последним кадром. getDeltaTime () в Libgdx и pSecondEplased в AndEngine

Tags: java, android, libgdx, andengine

pSecondEplased в движке AndEngine это время между текущим и последним кадром . точно такая же переменная есть в Libgdx . Эта переменная нужна  , чтобы анимация была более сглаженная. Но как самому посчитать это время? и где в этих движках код который реализует этот метод ? Ничего не нашел кроме этого в движке AndEngine ` private long mLastTick;
    private float mSecondsElapsedTotal;

```
void onTickUpdate()  {
    final long secondsElapsed = this.getNanosecondsElapsed();
    this.onUpdate(secondsElapsed);
}

private long getNanosecondsElapsed() {
    final long now = System.nanoTime();

    return now - this.mLastTick;
}

public void onUpdate(final long pNanosecondsElapsed)  {
    final  float pSecondsElapsed = pNanosecondsElapsed * 0.0000000001f;

    this.mSecondsElapsedTotal += pSecondsElapsed;
    this.mLastTick += pNanosecondsElapsed;
}`
```

Но мне все равно не хватает понимания того в какой момент времени должен запускаться метод , чтобы правильно считать это время и почему то когда я запускаю метод void onTickUpdate()  через другой класс показывается ссылка на нулевой объект ..

Comment: Я так понимаю, есть другие способы чтобы графика была плавной. Например задавать Fps , но этот способ позволяет выдавать максимально возможное Fps , как говорят критичен для батарейки , но тем не менее именно этот метод реализуется движками

Comment: ВОЗНИК еще вопрос: эта getDeltaTime() или pSecondsElapsed (в EndAngine) нужна чтобы кадры были плавнее. Если за секунду должен пройти 100, а кадр обработался за пол секунды , мы получил умножив на это время 50. и картинка будет соответствовать действительности. Но ведь есть ФПС которое так же используется для того чтобы картинка соответствовала действительности. ставим 60 кадров в секунду и всё идет плавно. Что лучше использовать? или это одно и тоже ? или лучше использовать и то и другое?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы вручную посчитать промежуток времени между текущим кадром и предыдущим, делать это нужно в так называемом главном цикле. В libgdx главным циклом является метод render. И getDeltaTime() использовать очень удобно, т.к. система сама засекает это время. Дальше, например, умножив его на скорость движения какого-нибудь объекта, получаем расстояние в пикселах, которое пробегает/пролетает объект за 1 кадр.

Но сделать это несложно и вручную даже без libgdx просто на java. Задаём 2 переменные типа long: currentKadrTime, PrevKadrTime. 
**В главном цикле** текущего экрана пишем:
currentKadrTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
float delta = currentKadrTime - PrevKadrTime; 
PrevKadrTime = currentKadrTime:
Полученная delta это и есть тоже, что и getDeltaTime() в libgdx - время между кадрами. Сорри, но про AndEngine ничего не знаю.

Когда я начал изучать Android Studio и Libgdx, то попробовал написать известный пример [игры с падающими каплями](http://www.libgdx.ru/2013/09/simple-game.html) сначала на libgdx, а потом без libgdx просто рисованием на канве. И применил описанный выше способ. В обоих случаях движение капелек получилось плавным.

Если говорить про fps, то можно его искусственно ограничить например так: задать константу в миллисекундах, чтобы кадры прорисовывались не чаще, чем через этот промежуток времени. опять же в главном цикле перед рисованием проверяем условие: если (текущее время) минус (последнее засечённое время перед обнулением) больше или равно константе, то рисуем сцену. Это действительно снизит нагрузку и сэкономит батарейку.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался и особенно интересно насчет ограничения fps , если не ошибаюсь в AndEngine так и работает, просто только когда вы сказали я понял , что там было написано . Осталось ограничить немного и всё заработает так как я хочу.